# Angular operations with arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

**Hi!**
I'm a beginner in Angular, and haven't really found anything for this, so if you can help me...please.
Here's an array

```
firstarray[] = [{id:1,name:abc},{id:2,name:cba},{id:3,name:asd}]
```

What I'd like to do is:
**First**: I have an index, for example `indexNum = 1`;
Then I want a new array with `firstarray`'s index items, the index is 1, so these would be id:2 and name:cba.

```
indexItems[] = {2,cba}
```

**Secondly**:
I want to make two new arrays from the `firstarray` one stores **only the ids** and the other stores **only the names**.

```
id_array[] = {1,2,3}  

name_array[] = {abc,cba,asd}
```

Comment: Note that none of this really is angular- or typescript-specific.  This is more general, plain javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first task, you should just use the index of the first array in creating the second.

```
var indexItems = [firstArray[index]];
```

I'm not sure why you'd need to build an array containing just one item though, since it'd be a little easier to work with the item if it weren't wrapped in the array, such as:

```
var indexItem = firstArray[index];
```

For the second task, the `map` function is convenient for mapping one array to a transformed array. Note also that you probably need to quote your strings in your array.  (I am assuming they're not variable names.)

```
// [{id:1,name:'abc'},{id:2,name:'cba'},{id:3,name:'asd'}]  
var nameArray = firstArray.map(item => item.name);
// ['abc', 'cba', 'asd']
var idArray = firstArray.map(item => item.id);
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I get all of the data here https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST**

```
indexItems= Object.values(firstarray[1])
```

**SECOND**

```
valsArr1=[]
valsArr2=[]
firstarray.forEach(item=>{
valsArr1.push(item['id']);
valsArr2.push(item['name']);
})
```